# Google glass programming

Tags: android, google-glass

I need to start up a project with Google Glass, but I have no Glass nor access to the API available at the moment. Since it runs on Android 4.0, can I program something for my Android phone and let it run on the Glasses eventually? Or would that be too much of a hassle?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it on google already: https://developers.google.com/glass/gdk

Answer (score 0):

There is an inofficial google glass emulator, but I never used it:

http://glass-apps.org/google-glass-emulator

Comment: Thanks, but since this is an Corporate project I am going to try to get Glasses ;)

Comment: Yes, much better idea ;)